# What is the best way to convert english sentences into ruby key-value pair?

Tags: ruby

I want to convert following sentences in key-value pair like ({total_amount: discount_amount}).

```
$10 off $30 of food #should return {30: 10}
$30 of awesome for $10 #should return {30: 20}
$20 Sneakers for $5 #should return {20: 15}
```

How can I handle this? It would be helpful If I can get any hint to start with...

Comment: You can use the [`String::scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan) method to extract the digits into an array and then convert the elements of the array into a hash.

Comment: A symbol cannot start with a number.

Comment: The downvote and vote to close are because your question is not clear. You need to edit to explain *why* "$10 off $30 of food" should return `{30=>10}`, whereas "$20 sneakers for $5" should return `{20=>15}`. Does it depend on whether the word "off" or "for" appears between the dollar amounts (as I assumed in my answer)? Also you can write `{a: 1}` to mean `{:a=>1}`, but `:10` is not a valid symbol, so you must write `{10=>1}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that each sentence of interest looks like this:

```
$XX....for....$YY
```

or like this:

```
$XX....off....$YY
```

where `XX` and `YY` are non-negative integers and `"for"` and `"off"` are key words that tell you what is to be done with the two numbers. If so, it seems that you want this:

```
arr = ["$10 off $30 of food", "$30 of awesome for $10", "$20 Sneakers for $5"]
```

Let's first define a regular expression in extended mode:

```
r = /
    \$        # match dollar sign
    (\d+)     # match one or more digits in capture group 1
    .*?       # match any number of any character lazily
    \b        # word boundary (so "buzzoff" is not matched)
    (for|off) # match "for" or "off" in capture group 2
    \b        # another word boundary
    .*?       # match any number of any character lazily  
    \$        # match dollar sign
    (\d+)     # match one or more digits in capture group 3
    /x        # extended mode for regex def

arr.each_with_object([]) do |s,a|
  s[r]
  f,l = $1.to_i, $3.to_i
  case $2
  when "for" then a << [f,f-l]
  when "off" then a << [l,f]
  end
end
  #=> [[30, 10], [30, 20], [20, 15]]
```

Here are the steps:

```
enum = arr.each_with_object([])
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["$10 off $30 of food", "$30 of awesome for $10",
  #  "$20 Sneakers for $5"]:each_with_object([])>
```

We can use [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) to pass each element of `enum` to the block and assign it to the block variables:

```
s, a = enum.next
  #=> ["$10 off $30 of food", []] 
s #=> "$10 off $30 of food" 
a #=> []
```

We now perform the block calculations:

```
s[r] #=> "10 off $30"
```

The values of the three capture groups are:

```
$1 #=> "10" 
$2 #=> "off" 
$3 #=> "30"
```

Therefore:

```
  f,l = $1.to_i, $3.to_i
    #=> [10, 30]
```

so:

```
  case $2
    when "for" then a << [f,f-l]
    when "off" then a << [l,f]
  end
```

is:

```
  case "off"
    when "for" then [] << [10, 10-30]
    when "off" then [] << [30, 10]
  end
    #=> [[30, 10]] 

  a #=> [[30, 10]]
```

The remaining calculations are performed similarly.

Answer (score 1):

```
def read_discount(file_name)
    File.foreach(file_name) do |line|
        /[^\d]*(\d+)[^\d]*(\d+)/ =~ line
        puts "#{$1}:#{$2}" if $1
    end
end

read_discount("31621358.txt")
```