# Regex to find strings with only letters or numbers or both

Tags: ruby, regex

I am searching for strings with only letters or numbers or both. How could I write a regex for that?

Comment: Check http://rubular.com/ and http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html

Answer (score 6):

You can use following `regex` to check if the string contains letters and/or numbers

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

**Explanation**

1. `^`: Starts with
2. `[]`: Character class
3. `a-zA-Z`: Matches any alphabet
4. `0-9`: Matches any number
5. `+`: Matches previous characters one or more time
6. `$`: Ends with

[**RegEx101 Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/jF5uG9/1)

Comment: Good answer. When answering questions involving regexes I often find it useful to express the regex in extended mode, which makes it self-documenting. An example is my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31621358/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-english-sentences-into-ruby-key-value-pair/31621565#31621565).

Comment: I recommend using `\A` / `\z` (start / end of string) instead of `^` / `$` (start / end of line) in Ruby even if the string might not ever contain newline characters.

Comment: Thanks for explaining each pattern operator in expression

Answer (score 3):

```
"abc&@*(2743438" !~ /[^a-z0-9]/i # => false
"abc2743438"     !~ /[^a-z0-9]/i # => true
```

Answer (score 0):

This example let to avoid multiline anchors use (**^** or **$**) (which may present a security risk) so it's better to use **\A** and **\z**, or to add the :multiline => true option in Rails.
Only letters and numbers:

```
/\A[a-zA-Z0-9]+\z/
```

Or if you want to leave - and _ chars also:

```
/\A[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+\z/
```

Comment: They want only letters and digits

Comment: Edited for both cases